# sscanf stopped working when upgrading to v141?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a code that works just fine when compiled with the build tools v110. Recently I have upgraded the toolchain to v141 (vs 2k17) and some functions that made use of sscanf is not working anymore.

The sscanf calls that stopped working make use of this particular format string: `"%s %[^\0]"`. It expects a stream string containing 1 string followed by a whitespace and another string which have to be put in a buffer for later treat. The first string is copied to the first buffer correctly but the second is not (sscanf returns 1 instead of 2).

Someone having this problem or have any idea of why it is happening?

A code sample to test the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[100], str2[100];

    memset(str1, 0, sizeof(str1));  memset(str2, 0, sizeof(str2));

    int i = sscanf("+nf foo", "%s %[^\0]", str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And also tell us what input you give to the function. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well... Idk what information you need besides that (and the input string), please let me know what exactly you need. The input string ("+nf off") is a string that should match the format string (it match when compiled with v110).

Comment: Read [mcve] and create a __complete__ program (that reproduces the problem) that we can cut/paste into our favourite tool chain and test it.  Should be less than approx 10 lines of code for this issue.

Comment: I just updated the question, please see above.

Comment: maybe the warning matters, no clue about sscanf syntax....

warning: no closing ']' for '%[' format [-Wformat=]
     int i = sscanf("+nf foo", "%s %[^\0]", str1, str2);

Comment: Try `%[\001-\377]`.

Comment: @n.m.That worked as expected. May you explain what that stands for?

Comment: @n.m. I'll wait a bit more for you to create an answer so I can accept. If you don't I'll answer myself and quote you. Ty.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: BTW, you do know that the embedded NUL (spelt `\0`) gives a syntactically invalid conversion specification, by ending the string before `]`, don't you?  You may have been previously (un)lucky that a standard library implementation inferred the close bracket for you.

Comment: @TobySpeight Ye man, It worked on the vc-110, but as I said when updating it to v141 it stopped working, probably someone fixed the problem. The solution that the user n.m. gave works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence `\0` encodes a zero byte (ASCII character NUL), which in C/C++ is a string terminator.

So your formatting string is effectively `"%s %[^"` with another one-char long string `"]"` possibly following it (*possibly*, because the compiler may notice the string termination and discard the unused tail).

**Edit**

As a string terminator, the NUL character actually can't appear in the input string (although it *could* appear e.g. in a file stream! I'm not sure, however, how that would be handled by `fscanf()`), so you need not look for it with the format specifier. If you just need to read both parts of an input string into two `char` arrays, just use `"%s%s"`:

```
    sscanf("+nf foo", "%s%s", str1, str2);
```

Comment: Hum I see, any tips on how to get over it?

Comment: @ptr0x You could use some other method to separate the strings, like searching for the dividing space? Perhaps using plain [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) might be enough in this case?

Comment: @ptr0x Please see the expanded answer.

Comment: Well, thanks @CiaPan I really don't know why there was in my head I should use the "%[^\0]" in that case.

Comment: @ptr0x Be careful though, it won't handle if there are spaces in the second string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought that too but it seems to work even with spaces o.O I'm kinda confused right now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude a guy from the topic comments gave a solution by using "%[\001-\377]". Do you knew that? I'm searching here but didn't figure out yet why he used \377 as the max range of a byte would be \255.

Comment: @ptr0x No those numbers are in [*octal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) notation.

Comment: @ptr0x You're wrong. The char constant notation with backslash uses **octal** system, so `'\377'` is `(char)255`, and `'\255'` corresponds to char code `173`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There's no such thing like 'spaces in the second string' unless one uses the `"%[...]"` format specifier. Ordinary specifiers, `"%s"` among them, cause `scanf` family functions to treat whitespace characters as fields' separators, so another space does not make 'a space in the second string' but rather 'a separator and a third string'.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the user n.m. in the topic comments the string I was using ("`%[^\0]`") don't work because the char "`\0`" will be translated to a ASCII NUL ending the format string before the proper end of the specifier `%[]`.
The correct string to use in this case (when you need to use the specifier `%[]` to read all the bytes instead of ASCII NUL) is "`%[\1-\377]`"